# Simple String Manipulation

Tags: c++

Suppose we have `char *a ="Mission Impossible";`

If we give `cout<<*(a+1)`, then the output is `i`.

Is there any way to change this value, or this is not possible?

Comment: first, it has to be `const char* a = "mission possible"`
What do you expect the output to be? what do you want to change?

Comment: You can change a lot of values all over the place, but you really need to be more specific to get sensible results.

Comment: What do you mean by "change this value"?

Comment: @ Karl ... I meant to say that if I need to change the value of any character within "Mission Impossible". Now I understand that since it is a constant pointer, this is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this, but you have to make a copy of the string first because if you didn't, you'd be modifying memory you're not allowed to (where string literals are stored).

```
const char* a = "Mission Impossible"; // const char*, not char*, because we can't
                                      // modify its contents
char buf[80] = {}; // create an array of chars 80 large, all initialised to 0
strncpy(buf, a, 79); // copy up to 79 characters from a to buf

cout << *(buf + 1); // prints i

buf[1] = 'b';

cout << *(buf + 1); // prints b

*(buf + 1) = 't';

cout << buf[1]; // prints t
```

That said, if this exercise is not for learning purposes, it is highly recommended that you learn and use `std::string` rather than C-style strings. They are superior in almost every way and will result in far less frustration and errors in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a[] = "Mission Impossible";

a[1] = 'x';
```

String literals cannot be modified.  Typically they are placed a section of the binary that will be mapped read-only, therefore writing to them generates a fault.  (This is implementation-defined behavior, but this happens to be the most common implementation these days.)

By declaring the string as a character array it is writable.  The other alternative would be to duplicate the string literal into heap memory, either through `malloc`, `new`, or `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `char* a` is actually read-only and if you try to modify the content you will get undefined behavior. You should ideally declare `a` as `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to change that is doing `*(a+1)='value_you_want';`

This will change the content of a pointer (your case pointer is a+1) to the value you set.

Comment: I suppose you meant `*(a+1)`?

Comment: @fge isn't & supposed to modify the content of a pointer? If no then this is what I meant :)

Comment: This will work if the data is definitely mutable; if it might be a string constant like this, it's not a good idea, though.

Comment: Even if you correct the `&` to `*` as fge says, that's not legal code; you're not allowed to alter characters from character literals. It will work on some platforms and compilers, but not on others -- and it can have drastically bad effects.

Comment: Thanks for the correction guys. I didn't know about that until now.